# how to replace age with previous value + 1

Tags: r

I'm trying to replace missing age values in one wave by adding 1 to the value from the previous wave. So, for instance:

| ID | Age | Wave |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 20 | 1 |
| 1 | NA | 2 |
| 2 | 61 | 1 |
| 2 | NA | 2 |

would become

| ID | Age | Wave |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 20 | 1 |
| 1 | 21 | 2 |
| 2 | 61 | 1 |
| 2 | 62 | 2 |

Answer (score 1):

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  mutate(Age = case_when(is.na(Age) ~ lag(Age) + 1, 
                         TRUE ~ Age))

# A tibble: 4 x 3
     ID   Age  Wave
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1    20     1
2     1    21     2
3     2    61     1
4     2    62     2
```

Comment: Why use `case_when` instead of `if_else` in the two-branch case?

Comment: There is an error caused by "case_when" when I run it

Answer (score 1):

Base R

```
> ave(df$Age,df$ID,FUN=function(x){x[1]+seq_along(x)-1})
[1] 20 21 61 62
```

Answer (score 0):

With tidyverse, assuming your data is in `df` dataframe:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
    group_by(ID) %>% arrange(ID, Wave) %>%
    mutate(missing_grp = cumsum( (is.na(Age)!=is.na(lag(Age))) | !is.na(Age) )) %>%
    group_by(ID, missing_grp) %>%
    mutate(age_offset=cumsum(is.na(Age))) %>%
    group_by(ID) %>%
    fill(Age, .direction='down') %>%
    mutate(Age = Age + age_offset) %>%
    ungroup() %>% select(-missing_grp, -age_offset)
```

It works also with multiple successive missing ages.
For the following input:

```
df <- tribble(
    ~ID, ~Age, ~Wave,
    1,   21,    1,
    1,   NA,    2,
    2,   61,    1,
    2,   NA,    2,
    2,   NA,    3,
    2,   70,    4,
    2,   NA,    5,
    )
```

it returns:

```
# A tibble: 7 × 3
     ID   Age  Wave
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1    21     1
2     1    22     2
3     2    61     1
4     2    62     2
5     2    63     3
6     2    70     4
7     2    71     5
```

Answer (score 0):

In base R

```r
within(df, Age[is.na(Age)] <- Age[which(is.na(Age)) - 1] + 1)
#>   ID Age Wave
#> 1  1  20    1
#> 2  1  21    2
#> 3  2  61    1
#> 4  2  62    2
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have more than two waves, we could use the row number:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyverse)

df |>
  group_by(ID) |>
  fill(Age) |>
  mutate(Age = Age + row_number() - 1) |>
  ungroup()
```

Output:

```r
# A tibble: 5 × 3
     ID   Age  Wave
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1    21     1
2     1    22     2
3     2    61     1
4     2    62     2
5     2    63     3
```